# Hidden Bootstrap notification blocks buttons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I hope you can help me with my problem, because it seems quite odd to me.
On my website I'm using some [Bootstrap alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/) to inform the users in case of success or errors.

After some time the alert is hidden:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#alertLogged").removeClass("show");
}, 5000);
```

My problem is that, because of the alert being hidden, all buttons that are behind the alert are still not clickable.

I'll try to make a jsfiddle but I can't promise that it works because I've had some problems in the past.
Furthermore I#ve already tried to make the alert on bottom, which solved my problem of the buttons on top being not clickable.
But I think it looks better if the alerts are at the top of the website.

Beside that I've tried to destroy the alerty completely and not only hide it which solved the problem as well.

But this is no real solution because it will make more problems if I have to display another error/success message.

There is not much code to show here but as I said I'll try to give you a jsfiddle.

Hope some of you can help me, thanks in advance :)

#### UPDATE

Here's the HTML code of the "alertLogged" item. It is not much because I'm doing most of it in Java Script

```
<div class="hide fade text-center" role="alert" id="alertLogged"></div>
```

#### UPDATE 2

After joshmoto's answer I've tried to add something to my CSS file:

```
.alert:not(.show){
pointer-events: none;}
```

but it did not change anything...

#### UPDATE 3

In order to get Shidersz answer going (it looks quite nice and simple) I will post the code now:

```
alert("TEST");
$("#alertLogged").fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
alert("TEST2");
```

So the alert("TEST") is called but "TEST2" is not, furthermore, the alert does not show up.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle link

Comment: I'll try my best

Comment: I'm sorry it does not seem like I'm getting the jsfiddle done...

Comment: Provide html code of the element having id `alertLogged`

Comment: Could you elaborate why it's more difficult to show more alerts if one is removed from the DOM?

Comment: @Cue Because I use the alert for different purposes and different functions. If I remove it there will not be the chance for me to call it again in another case will it? So to make it clearer: I first display an error when function A is triggered. Then the user tries function B and it works. If function B works the same alert will be called but with a different text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simple use initilization of alert with `display:none` and then show and hide it using the JQuery methods `fadeIn()/fadeOut()`.

```html
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <div class="alert alert-info text-center" role="alert" id="alertLogged">
    Alert!
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAlert">
    Show Alert
  </button>

  <style>
    #alertLogged {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $("#btnAlert").click(function()
    {
      $("#alertLogged").fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you have some code overriding the style, alert can't show at begin if no one overrides the `display:none` style property I have added in particular to it. Are you wrapping each code into the section it should be (<script>,<style>, <body>, <head>)? A simple `copy->paste` won't work if you don't put each code where it should be.

Comment: I figuered out now and it works in general but as soon I add this method to my project, the alert appears but does not disappear. All my methods I want to call after the alert pops up are not called either

Comment: I have updated with a version where all code is wrapped inside his section. However, will be hard to guess what changes you need to do to include this into your current project. Good luck!

Comment: I've rechecked and everything is where it should be. Nothing seems to be overriding the #alertLogged part of my CSS file (might it be the bootstrap CSS?) but the alert is still not showing up and alle functions following aren't called...

Answer (score 2):

Its not full proof but you could maybe create your own class or add some css to position the alert somewhere else while it is hidden.

You could use `pointer-events: none;` css when the alert is not visible and extend your `.show` class to include `pointer-events: auto;`

That might be a quick fix if I'm understanding your question right.

---

**Update**

On the [bootstrap alerts page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/alerts/) if I remove the show class from the dom, the alert becomes invisible but it still acts as block element. Is your absolute positioned? Strange, I would of thought you could click through the hidden alert with `pointer-events: none;`

Try this css maybe..

```
.alert-dismissible {
  pointer-events: none; 
}

.alert-dismissible.show {
  pointer-events: auto; 
}
```

---

**Update 2**

Because you want to keep the alert in the dom at all times. Maybe just only use the `.alert` class and not use the `.alert-dismissible` classes.

When you are removing `.show` class, this will only change the opacity to 0. This is so the bootstrap dismissible animation can fade the alert out before destroying it.

Try loading your html with this class `.alert-hidden`.

```
.alert-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Then toggle this class as you need to with your script.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#alertLogged").addClass("alert-hidden");
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work, is my CSS okay or did I do it wrong?

Comment: The problem is, that I can't dismiss the alert (dismiss will remove it from th DOM if I understood that right?), because I'm useing the alert with different texts often throughout my script...

Comment: Weird... natively the alert is a block element positioned relative, so technically nothing could ever exist behind it, unless your buttons in question are positioned absolute.

Comment: Your correct, the dismiss function will remove the dom. OK, ill add another solution. 2 mins

Comment: I'll check if one of my mates I'm working with changed something lately but as far as I remember they are not...

Comment: So I talked to the mate who made the design on the site an he says thet the menu (it will be updated to a bootstrap navbar) is basically made up out of radio buttons that turn on and off the different menus. And I think that those radio buttons are positioned absolute. Okay the radio Buttons are in a div and this div is positioned absolute on the left side of the display

Comment: See my update, because your using the native `.alert-dismissible` class `.show`. When removing `.show` class will only change the opacity to 0. This is so the boostrap dismissible animation can fade the alert out before destroying it. So you will have to make you own alert hidden class. Or just use the `d-none` class. But you might be able to animate your own `.alert-hidden` class.

Comment: Thanks mate Update 2 seems to work :D, thanks for your time :)